# Taking lot of time to execute hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm fetching a result set using hibernate by making a simple "Select" query. But, its taking lot of time like 350ms, 400ms, 500ms.. Ideally it should not this much time for a simple query. When I reduce the caching mechanism, it retrieves fast. But, however it takes lot of time for the first time.

Here is my code

```
    public JSONObject getWidgetDetails(String userId) {
    log.info("[Widget][Get Details] Received UserID in Impl :"+userId);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
    try (Session session = factory.openSession()) {
        String hql = "FROM com.DashboardModel where uid = :id";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("id", userId);
        query.setCacheable(true);
        List<?> results = query.list();         
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();         
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            DashboardWidgetModel dwm = (DashboardWidgetModel) results.get(i);
            jObj.put(defaultWidget, (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(dwm.getDefaultWidget()));
            jObj.put(others, (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(dwm.getOthers()));
            jObj.put(widgetGalleryList, (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(dwm.getWidgetGalleryList()));
            jObj.put(widgetModelList, (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(dwm.getWidgetModelList()));
            jObj.put(dwUserId,(JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(dwm.getUserId()));
        }           
        obj.put(DashBoardStructure, jObj);
        log.info("[Widget][Get Details] Result Object :"+obj);
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.info("[Widget][Get Details] Time elapsed For Fetching :"
                + (lEndTime - lStartTime));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Can we make changes to the existing code to retrive in a faster manner? Any ideas would be appreicated.

Comment: Things to check: is `uid` and indexed field ? Are there any joins from this entity to others that may be causing sub-queries ?  What do you see on the console with debugging on ?

Comment: Your JSON parsing is part of your measured time. It's not the query that might be slow.

Comment: @jr593 uid is just a normal column in the table.. In the console, I see the time elapsed

Comment: @f1sh, can we refine it further to reduce the time?

Comment: Put your ``long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();`` right after ``List<?> results = query.list();``. Then you only get the time of the query, not the data processing.

Comment: @f1sh, I understand your point. But, rather can we do something for the data processing too?

Comment: You create a lot of `JsonParser`, can't you reuse it?

Comment: @Syed you could save the call to ``new JSONParser()`` in each element by refactoring it to a variable and use the same JSONParser instance for each of the 5 calls to ``parse``. There's no need to create a new instance in each row. But that shouldn't affect your time consumption significantly.

Comment: @f1sh, can you plz update the answer?

Comment: @f1sh, Understood your point. Thanks